# Fade in and out different messages

Tags: jquery

I need to display a few messages during a full minute after a userexecutes an action on click.

Is there a way to use delay() and chain those message somehow or do I next functions to start next message after the previous ends?

```
<div id="myMsgs"></div>

$('#myMsgs').text('message one').delay(20000).fadeOut('slow', function() 
{ 
    $('#myMsgs').text('message two').fadeIn('slow').delay(20000).fadeOut('slow', function() { ... });
});
```

My gut feeling tells me this is way too convoluted. There's gotta be a better way, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend straight setTimeout or equivalent for this rather than using pure jQuery in that way.  For example:

```
var showMessageOne = function() {
  $('#myMsgs').text('message one');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myMsgs').hide();
    showMessageTwo();
  }, 20000);

}

var showMessageTwo = function() {
  $('#myMsgs').text('message two');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myMsgs').hide();
  }, 20000);

}

$("#trigger").click(function(ev) {
  showMessageOne();
});
```

This is a bit cleaner, more explicit, and there is a clear readability about what "showMessageOne" is actually going to do.

That's a quick dirty example, you should absolutely refactor out the duplication, but I think you're example is somewhat contrived so I didn't want to dig to deep into that.